# how to disable current row items when check box enabled in a form in oracle apps

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-apps

My requirement is to create a new form with 7 fields Item1,item2,item3,item4, item5 and fully_processed_flag.

I had created a form and now when if i enabled fully_processed_flag then remaining items need to be disabled (need to grayed out).

So i had written below code in `WHEN CHECKBOX CHANGED` for fully_processed_flag item.

But i am getting this error

> FRM-41805: Ambiguous item name:ROWID.

and current row is grayed with different color which is different from oracle standards.

---

```
DECLARE
   LC$ITEM       VARCHAR2 (255);  
   LC$NAVIGABLE  VARCHAR2 (10);  
BEGIN  
   LC$ITEM := GET_BLOCK_PROPERTY (:SYSTEM.TRIGGER_BLOCK, FIRST_ITEM);  
   WHILE LC$ITEM IS NOT NULL  
   LOOP  
    LC$NAVIGABLE := GET_ITEM_PROPERTY (LC$ITEM, NAVIGABLE);  
    IF LC$NAVIGABLE = 'TRUE'  
    THEN  
      IF :ITEMS_DETAILS.FULLY_PROCESSED_FLAG = 'Y'  
      THEN  
     /* SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY (:ITEMS_DETAILS.ITEM2,  
                     CURRENT_RECORD,  
                     UPDATE_ALLOWED,
                     PROPERTY_FALSE);  */

       SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY (LC$ITEM,  
                     CURRENT_RECORD,  
                     VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE,  
                     'SELECTED');  
       SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY (LC$ITEM,  
                     CURRENT_RECORD,  
                     UPDATE_ALLOWED,  
                     PROPERTY_FALSE);       
       SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY (LC$ITEM,  
                     CURRENT_RECORD,  
                     INSERT_ALLOWED,  
                     PROPERTY_FALSE);  

      ELSE  
       SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY (LC$ITEM,  
                     CURRENT_RECORD,  
                     VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE,  
                     'UNSELECTED');  
       SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY (LC$ITEM,  
                     CURRENT_RECORD,  
                     UPDATE_ALLOWED,  
                     PROPERTY_TRUE);       
       SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY (LC$ITEM,  
                     CURRENT_RECORD,  
                     INSERT_ALLOWED,  
                     PROPERTY_TRUE);         
      END IF;  
    END IF;  
    LC$ITEM := GET_ITEM_PROPERTY (LC$ITEM, NEXT_NAVIGATION_ITEM);  
   END LOOP;  
 END;  
*****************************************************************************
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please edit your question and post whatever you've tried so far?

Comment: Hello redels,

i have edited the question with the code i had written.
Could you please check it and please provide me the solution